# Images are not getting displayed on my website (HTML)

Tags: javascript, python, html, django

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>AYNTK</title>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="templates\Slide 1.jpg" class="d-block w-100">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="templates\Slide 2.jpg" class="d-block w-100">
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="templates\Slide 3.jpg" class="d-block w-100">
        </div>
      </div>
      <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
      </button>
      <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleControls" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

 </body>
</html>
```

I am really new to designing with HTML and CSS... I took this code from Bootstrap website, trying to create a carousel and added the relative path of my images to the img tag as source. The images does not get displayed on the website.. What can possibly be the reason?

Comment: You should use slash `/` instead of backslash `\\` in the image file path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

host your images on Google drive as in upload them on Google drive , make them available for anyone within Google drive then copy the link for each image , place the link wherever you want that image in your code with in image tags and it's done bro.
Your images will be loaded.
Are you hosting it some where or your running it locally in your browser bro

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Change \ to / in `src` attribute of `img` tag as

```
<img src="templates/Slide 1.jpg" >
```